# Is Obfuscating Email with Javascript like this prevent Spam bot harvest?

Tags: javascript, email, obfuscation

I obfuscate this javascript:

```
document.write('email@domain.com');
```

at here: http://javascriptobfuscator.com/

and generated this:

```
var _0x20b1=["\x65\x6D\x61\x69\x6C\x40\x64\x6F\x6D\x61\x69\x6E\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D",
    "\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document[_0x20b1[1]](_0x20b1[0]);
```

Is this secure to prevent email from harvesting by spam bot?

Comment: Maybe about 20 years ago.

Comment: @j08691 Looks like javascript email obfuscation is outdated.